# Laravel relation data with first() method

Tags: php, laravel, relation

- Vender hasMany Banquet

Here is my query:

```
$banquet = Vendor::with(['banquet' => function($query){
         $query->where('active',1)->where('id' ,1)->first();
      }])->findOrfail(1);
```

but the relation part return an collection like `get()` method not `first()`

```
#relations: array:1 [▼
    "banquet" => Collection {#283 ▼
      #items: array:1 [▼
        0 => Banquet {#285 ▼
```

How to trans like this? So that I can just get the banquet data like `$vendor->banquet` not `$vendor->banquet[0]`

```
#relations: array:1 [▼
   "banquet" => Banquet {#285 ▼
```

Comment: You don't need first and findorfail at same time. Just try with findorfail and see how it returns

Comment: It`s all same .

Answer (score 0):

I think, you are using **OneToMany** for banquet.
  So, you are getting in the collection/array.

Please, try it as **OneToOne**. and say if you get any change or not.

```
return $this->belongsTo();
```

in banquet method.

or

```
return $this->hasOne();
```